# How to get enum variable name by value in golang?

Tags: go

I use enum to define the relationship between id and text value, but I use id as enum value, because I can't use id as variable name

```
type Gender uint8
type MemberType uint8

const (
    Male Gender = 2
    Female Gender = 5

    Standard MemberType = 2
    VIP MemberType = 5
)
```

Now I have selected the id 5 from Gender table and MemberType table, how can I use it to get the text "Female" for Gender, and the text "VIP" for MemberType?

Comment: Are you trying to convert a variable containing `5` to be a variable of type `Gender` equal to `Female`, or are you trying to put the string `"Female"` in a variable?

Comment: I want to convert the id to text for display

Comment: @CLSo which one is the "id"? is it the "Male" or "2" ?

Comment: 2 is id, Male is the text for display

Comment: There are no enums in go 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the strings "Female" and "VIP"

```
var genders = map[uint8]string{
    2: "Male",
    5: "Female",
}

var memberTypes = map[uint8]string{
    2: "Standard",
    5: "VIP",
}
```

or:

```
var genders = map[Gender]string{
    Male: "Male",
    Female: "Female",
}

var memberTypes = map[MemberType]string{
    Standard: "Standard",
    VIP: "VIP",
}
```

and then you'll have something like

```
 id := 5
 fmt.Println(genders[id]) // "Female"
 fmt.Println(memberTypes[id]) // "VIP"
 // or...
 fmt.Println(genders[Gender(id)]) // "Female"
 fmt.Println(memberTypes[MemberType(id)]) // "VIP"
```

Comment: I would prefer `stringer` to auto generate that map-to-string code for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [godoc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer). 
There is generator for this job, called **`stringer`**, under `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer`

With **`stringer`**, you can do it like this.

```golang
/*enum.go*/

//go:generate stringer -type=Pill
type Pill int

const (
    Placebo Pill = iota
    Aspirin
    Ibuprofen
    Paracetamol
    Acetaminophen = Paracetamol
)
```

Save `enum.go`, then just run `go generate`. stringer will have every done for you.

```
in the same directory will create the file pill_string.go, in package 
painkiller, containing a definition of

func (Pill) String() string

That method will translate the value of a Pill constant to the string
representation of the respective constant name, so that the call

fmt.Print(painkiller.Aspirin)

will print the string "Aspirin".
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the selected id to `Gender` type. Example:

```golang
selectedID := 5
selectedGender := Gender(selectedID)
fmt.Println(selectedGender == Female) // true

anotherSelectedID := 5
selectedMemberType := MemberType(anotherSelectedID)
fmt.Println(selectedMemberType == VIP) // true
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/pfmJ0kg7cO3

Comment: I want to convert the id to text for display

Answer (score 0):

> you can have the seperate method for each enum-type to get the string
>   value like this:-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Gender uint8
type MemberType uint8

const (
    Male     Gender     = 2
    Female   Gender     = 5
    Standard MemberType = 2
    VIP      MemberType = 5
)

func (data Gender) String() string {
    switch data {
    case Male:
        return "Male"
    case Female:
        return "Female"
    default:
        return "unknown"
    }
}

func (data MemberType) String() string {
    switch data {
    case Standard:
        return "Standard"
    case VIP:
        return "VIP"
    default:
        return "unknown"
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Male.String())
    fmt.Println(Female.String())
    fmt.Println(VIP.String())
    fmt.Println(Standard.String())
}
```

> playground url:-https://play.golang.org/p/JIdXUC8BFML

Answer (score 0):

Found the other code blocks seemed to miss the ability to reverse lookup strings by simply making a map[string]CustomType{}

Example:

```golang
type ReleaseType int

const (
    Release ReleaseType = 1
    Beta    ReleaseType = 2
    Alpha   ReleaseType = 3
)

var releaseLookup = map[string]ReleaseType{
    "release": Release,
    "beta":    Beta,
    "alpha":   Alpha,
}

func (app *appEnv) fromArgs(args []string) error {
    ...
    inputReleaseType := fl.String("r", "release", "Mods release type, release, beta, alpha")
    app.modReleaseType = releaseLookup[*inputReleaseType]
```